# converting white spaces into command-line type spaces

Tags: java, escaping

I am writing a java program in which I need to precede spaces in filenames by `\`. For example `two word filename.ext` will be `two\ word\ filename.ext`

I tried `System.out.println(str.replaceAll(" ","\ "));` but it says illegal escape character at `\` and `System.out.println(str.replaceAll(" ","\\ "));` doesn't affect the string.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `replace` method to specify the exact `String` to use as a replacement.

```
String str = "space now please";
System.out.println(str.replace(" ","\\ "));
```

prints

```
space\ now\ please
```

You need to escape the `\` character in `String` literals, so it would be `"\\"`.

Comment: I didn't know that `System.out.println(str.replace(" ","\\ "));` works too.Why replaces all whitespaces instead of the first one? Anyway, +1.

Comment: @rpax The answer is in the Javadoc. Basically, with `replaceAll`, the replacement String is a special `String` expression used by `java.util.Matcher`. `Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string`. `replace` doesn't have such problems, but doesn't use regular expressions to match values.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `replace ... doesn't use regular expressions to match values` true, but lets keep things more clearly. This sentence doesn't mean that regex engine is not used here at all. `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` uses regex engine internally, but before using it automatically escapes all metacharacters from regex (using `Pattern.LITERAL` flag) and replacement (using `Matcher.quoteReplacement` method).

Comment: @Pshemo I guess it's semantics. But note that nothing in the specification of `replace(..)` says anything about how the replacing is achieved. The Oracle JDK 7 implementation uses the regex engine, but it doesn't _have to_. I could have been more clear, but it's a comment, bleh, can't edit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(" ","\\\\ "));
```